# How to run Google Chrome without VNC

Tags: google-chrome, xfce, vnc

**This is what I want to do** (just in case my question is an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem))
I want to run a Chrome Extension in my VPS, 24/7, even after a system restart or Chrome crash (need a way to restart Chrome automatically).
Chrome extension is automatic, so I guess running Chrome Broweser is enough.

**This is what I got:**
My VPS does not have a desktop environment, I have installed xfce4 and tightvncserver. Then I connect via VNCViewer and it starts with XFCE open, I run Chrome there and the extension works fine.

**Problems:**
1) If I kill vncserver process (I want to do this for security reasons) then chrome stop working (I think maybe vncserver is the one starting XFCE and then Chrome?)
2) I don't know how to make this robust against crashes and restarts (I have added "@reboot google-chrome --no-sandbox" to my crontab but I think that won't work, and that won't restart Google Chrome if it crashes)

Any suggestion/solution? (I'm really noob in Ubuntu and server things)

Comment: You can search for howto add a program to xfce session startup, ...I think there is `~/.config/autostart` or similar. Also, Chrome might have an option to restart itself if a crash happens, and you are welcome to search for that too.

Comment: THanks @mikewhatever but I think that does not solve problem 1) xfce seems to be running only with vncserver, I don't want to keep running vncserver (but I want to run it and see my current xfce)

Comment: So now you know what problem you need to solve, don't you?

Comment: I don't understand your comment, if you know the solution can you put it in a new answer?